# Is there a way to guarantee inserts of unique values in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, unique-key

I have a table with user data in Azure SQL. I'm wondering if there's a not complicated way to insert unique value like this:

- I have a `Name` column in table and for example I have the names: Mirco, Dani, Elena
- If a user wants to insert "Dani" as name, I would like that SQL automatically inserts "Dani2" instead

Any idea how to achieve that?

PS: I'm using Entity Framework as ORM

Comment: There's no automagic way, no. You would need to define some logic in your insertion process; likely in the procedure your application calls.

Answer (score 0):

As @larnu said in comments there is no direct or automatic way to insert unique values in sql. You can assign [**`unique constraint`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16#to-create-a-unique-constraint-on-a-new-table) to column so that if the value you want to enter is already exist in column or table it will throw an exception as value already exist (SQLException e)